# push notifications not received on Xiomi when app not running

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app able to receive push notification when app is not running on Motorola with Lollipop, But Xiomi with Lollipop unable to receive notification if app is not running.

Anyhow if app is opened it is able to receive notifications.

Is there any problem in Xiomi phones ?

Here is my manifest file permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.localmarket.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<permission
    android:name="com.uignet.localmarket.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: does it have google play services ?

Comment: is google play service is same as google play app? if it is , then yes it has.

Comment: I wonder why is it down voted, It is a genuine question. If this issue is related to google play service then what does google play app installed by default will do? I see lot of URLs exists to download playservices seperately on Xiomi.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that Xiomi phones has a setting "Auto Start" for the apps to receive notifications in the background. It is disabled by default. That's the reason its not receiving notifications. Just enable it make it work. and also enable notifications for the apps installed.

Comment: Then how to tackle this problem?? Any permissions needed because Gmail is pushing notifications even after disabling autostart permission... Any idea..?

Comment: I can't find this "Auto Start" option anywhere, would you please help me out in this?

Comment: I found this "Auto Start" option but is there any way to programatically turn on "Auto Start" ?